# Visual studio completion python

Tags: python, visual-studio, ptvs

I'm new to python in visual studio..I'm trying to have the same environment of sublime text.
I configured everything auto-formatting , auto-completion etc...
But when I write essential keyword like "self", the tool doesn't suggest me the keyword
So if I write "s" in sublime I obtain a suggest for "self".
But this don't happen in visual studio.
Is it normal? what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

PTVS will only use autocomplete functionality in certain scenarios.  In order for 'self' to display after typing 's' you will need to press CTR+SPACE or CTR+J.  These are the default commands for autocomplete.  You can learn more at the [completion page](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Editor-Features#completions) of the wiki.

Here's an excerpt:

> Completions can be shown at any time by pressing Ctrl+J or Ctrl+Space, or may be triggered automatically by certain commands (such as import), operators (such as a period/full stop), or by typing at any place where completions are likely to be helpful.